# Wordpress facebook comment plugin is displayed on top

Tags: css, wordpress

have a small problem with facebook comments. For some reason my theme is not very compatible with the plugin.

[image]

If you click to inspect the element, it will fix on it's own then (no idea why).
Also I would like if you add more text into the comment box the content below the box doesn't move down. So is there a way to align the box correctly only with the css? ( I have tried 2-3 different plugins, but I had the same problem)

**Website:** http://www.viskasseimai.lt/

P.S. it works great on a singple post, but something is wrong inside the home page...

**Plugin used:** https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/facebookall/page/3

Comment: Do you need your `.blog-grid`s displayed as absolute? What's happening here is that these elements have their `top` positioning defined before the facebook comment boxes are appended, so these values can't accommodate this change since they are declared before it happens

Comment: Yes this works, but how exactly I can describe the class? Because if I just chage .blog-grid it will not work. And I couldn't find where it would be set as absolute in the css.

Comment: If you inspect the element in question you should notice them declared as inline styles. This means you'll need to use the `!important` declaration to over-qualify them with external styles, e.g: `.blog-grid {position: relative !important; top: auto !important;}`

Comment: If you can add it to the answer, but use this class: .blog-grid.element.column-1.masonry-brick  , otherwise it won't work. I will mark it after you post your answer.

Comment: No problem, answer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the `absolute` positioning of the `.blog-grid` elements. The `position` and `top` values are explicitly declared and set as inline styles before the facebook comment box is appended to the element. So these calculations don't factor in the additional element because they occur before it's introduced.

**CSS**

```
.blog-grid.element.column-1.masonry-brick {
    position: relative !important;
    top: auto !important;
}
```

The above rules will over-qualify the inline rules for every instance of the element since the `!important` declaration has been used.
If you want these rules to only apply to the home page, add `.home` as a preceding selector before `.blog-grid`, same methodology would apply to archive pages or specific taxonomy type pages.

Comment: Thanks, spent a lot of time on that, but it was really easy to fix.

Comment: @Frutis it turns out to be that way occasionally, especially where CSS is concerned - glad I could help you find your solution.